# PIGPIO debounce

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have tried to do debounce using the pigpio library but it wasn't successful

```
import pigpio
captureFlag=1
pi=pigpio.pi()
def ImgCap(gpio.level.ticks):
    global captureFlag
    if captureFlag==0:
        print "OFF"
    if captureFlag==1:
        captureflag=0
        print "call back"
        for x in xrange (1000000):
              x=x+1
        print x
        captureflag=1
def main():
      calf=pi.callback(4,pigpio.RISING_EDGE,ImgCap)
      while True:
           pass
if __name__=='__main__'
      main()
```

This wasn't successful callback never prints OFF and it keeps printing the call back and x value continuously.
What have I done wrong how to code the debounce correctly.
What are the other possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Your program never prints "Off" because the variable you are testing for is never set to 0 when the callback is triggered.

I would suggest you look at the standard RPi.GPIO library (the one that comes built in to Raspbian), because it handles switch bounce natively, as well as allow you to set a callback for the rising and falling edge in one function using `GPIO.BOTH`.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)

def ImgCap(channel):
    print("Flag Captured?")

GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.BOTH, callback=ImgCap, bouncetime=200)

while True:
    pass
```

See http://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges